# Jquery: val() float numbers - need to change values, not concatenate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation, parsefloat

I need to convert a number in an input text type field from Celsius to Kelvin when radio buttons switch:

```
$('input[name=temperature]').click(function(){

    var tempType = $('input[name=temperature]:checked').val();

    if( tempType == 'celsius' ){
        $('.scale').html('°C');
        if( $('#t1').val() && $('#t2').val() ){
            var kt1 = parseFloat( kelvinToCelsius( $('#t1').val() ) );
            var kt2 = parseFloat( kelvinToCelsius( $('#t2').val() ) );

            //$('#t1').val( '' );
            //$('#t2').val( '' );

            $('#t1').val( kt1 );
            $('#t2').val( kt2 );
        }//if
    }//celsius
    else if( tempType == 'kelvin' ){
        $('.scale').html('K');
         if( $('#t1').val() && $('#t2').val() ){
            var kt1 = parseFloat( celsiusToKelvin( $('#t1').val() ) );
            var kt2 = parseFloat( celsiusToKelvin( $('#t2').val() ) );


            $('#t1').val( kt1 );
            $('#t2').val( kt2 );
        }//if
    }//kelvin
});

function kelvinToCelsius( kelvinTemp){
      return kelvinTemp - 273.15;
}//kelvinToCelsius

function celsiusToKelvin( celsiusTemp){
    return celsiusTemp + 273.15;
}//celsiusToKelvin
```

the number in the input field results as a concatenation of the previus value (maybe jQuery threats them as strings, not numbers).

I even tried to add parseFloat() to each variable but the situation doesn't change.

I want to change the values, not to concatenate them: how can I get that?

Thank you!

Comment: What you're describing doesn't happen with the example code you've shown. There's something else in your code that concatenates the values. You'll have to show an example that replicates the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I added the code

Comment: The problem is with the functions `kelvinToCelsius()` and/or `celsiusToKelvin()`. Show them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this line:

```
var kt1 = parseFloat( celsiusToKelvin( $('#t1').val() ) );
```

That gets the string value from `#t1` (`value` in `input` elements is always a string) and passes it into `celsiusToKelvin`. Then, once `celsiusToKelvin` is done with what it's doing, it parses what it gets back as a float.

`celsiusToKelvin` is expecting to receive a *number*, not a string. You want to parse *before* calling it:

```
var kt1 = celsiusToKelvin( parseFloat( $('#t1').val() ) );
```

That way, when `celsiusToKelvin` does

```
return celsiusTemp + 273.15;
```

...it's doing *addition*, not string concatenation.

Once you have the resulting *number* in `kt1`, this line:

```
$('#t1').val( kt1 );
```

...implicitly converts it to a string as part of setting the value on the input.